# Is it okay to bring up a discussion that happened long ago?

Tags: discussion, meta

I have seen some pretty popular discussions that happened long ago, and some of them seem pretty good, despite being declined. Some of them are declined because of some circumstances that existed long ago, but no longer do today. In such case, can such a discussion be brought up again?

Comment: Don't you think that this qn is not a duplicate of the one marked above?  Both are different imho

Comment: @Dawny33 I may have not written much in this question. But the suggested dupe is pretty what I wanted to ask anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**

If you think it would help the community get more clarity on the topic discussed, then you can definitely bring up the discussion. But, please don't forget to quote the posts or lines from the posts which you want to follow-up from.

Also, if it is just a minor doubt/query, then a better idea is to leave a comment under the respective post(s).

Comment: _from the posts which you want to follow-up from._ It'll help to find dupes easily